# Image viewer using gtk

Tags: image, gtk

I am working on a  image viewer .I want to create a a area where thumbnails of all the images in the folder will be displayed(like eye of gnome).Any one have any idea how to do it using Gtk?

Comment: Please provide more information. What language are you using? What have you tried? A GtkGrid is good enought for you, or are you looking for something more specific?

Comment: i am using c++ and gtkmm.I have already created a image viewer that can load ,change size and even apply mask on the image.I want to display the thumbnails of all image in the folder like eye of gnome.

Comment: If you want to find out how EOG does it, then look in the EOG sources.

Comment: Perfectly agree with ptomato: nothing better than a full-immersion into sane C code to clean yourself from C++. They use a custom widget derived from GtkBox: http://git.gnome.org/browse/eog/tree/src/eog-thumb-nav.c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can emulate the Eye Of Gnome behaviour by using an horizontal GtkBox inside an horizontal GtkScrollbar. Just add your thumbnails to the GtkBox, and that's it:

```
+------------------------------------+
|                                    |
|                                    |
|                                    |
|       Your image viewer            |
|                                    |
|                                    |
|                                    |
+------------------------------------+
| GtkBox                             |
| +--------------------------------+ |
| |            |            |      | |
| | Thumbnail1 | Thumbnail2 | Th...| |
| |            |            |      | |
| +--------------------------------+ |
+------------------------------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to use the [GtkIconView](http://www.gtk.org/api/2.6/gtk/GtkIconView.html) widget.